# How do I can insert array in multiple rows in psql using knexjs

Tags: javascript, postgresql, psql, knex.js

I am using transaction outta knexjs to insert values in 2 tables (1. result, 2. result detail). while inserting values in table 2 (resultdetail), I have an array of objects whose size varies with every entry (based on no. of subjects).

```js
{
 "name": "Sally",
 "fathername": "John",
 "rollno": "85a76",
 "classname": "class1",
 "detail": [
  {
   "subject": "History",
   "marksobt": "50",
   "totalmarks": "100"
  },
  {
   "subject": "French",
   "marksobt": "75",
   "totalmarks": "75"
  }
 ]
}
```

I am trying following code to do this. (Again, the size of "detail" array varies with no. of subjects)

```js
const { name, fathername, rollno, classname } = req.body;
 db.transaction(trx => {
  db.insert({
   name: name,
   fathername: fathername,
   rollno: rollno,
   classname: classname
  }).into('results')
  .transacting(trx)
  .returning('rollno')
  .then(roll_no => {
   req.body.detail.map(result => {
    return trx('resultdetail')
    .returning('*')
    .insert({
     rollno: roll_no[0],
     subject: result.subject,
     marksobt: result.marksobt,
     totalmarks: result.totalmarks
    }).then(console.log)
   })
  })
  .then(trx.commit)
  .catch(trx.rollback)
 })
 .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))
```

But end up getting following error.

```js
Unhandled rejection Error: Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insertedRows = await knex('results').returning('*').insert([
    {
        "subject": "History",
        "marksobt": "50",
        "totalmarks": "100"
    },
    {
        "subject": "French",
        "marksobt": "75",
        "totalmarks": "75"
    }
]);
```

But mainly your problem is that you launch multiple queries + commit at the same time without waiting that earlier queries are ready...

When you add stuff to second table it should be something like this:

```
.then(roll_no => {
  let resultsToAdd = req.body.detail.map(result => {
     return {
       rollno: roll_no[0],
       subject: result.subject,
       marksobt: result.marksobt,
       totalmarks: result.totalmarks
     };
   });

   return return trx('resultdetail')
     .returning('*')
     .insert(resultsToAdd);
})
```